# generating tick data from OHLC using simulations in R

Tags: r, simulation

I have a project where I have been asked to use OHLC stock price data to simulate tick data (hourly or minute frequency is my choice) using random number generators and simulation in R. My constraint is that the data should be bound by the Low and High during the day. Which function in R can I use for starting such a project.. I can post code here as I make progress - any suggestions would be very helpful

Comment: Perhaps a place to start is `?Distributions` as it outlines several different distributions, most/all of which have random number generators. You can also look at `arima.sim()` to simulate a time series data if the structure of the error terms are important to you.

Comment: thanks @Chase, it sounds like arima.sim() might be a place for me to start

Comment: If you only have open and close, that is easy: it is called a bridge (often a [Brownian bridge](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brownian_bridge), if the process was a Brownian motion, but that can be generalized). But if you have open, high, low and close, that does not look easy at all. It was discused, but not really answered, on [quant.stackexchange](http://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/2567/how-to-create-a-stochastic-process-through-pre-specified-points).

Comment: thanks @VincentZoonekynd, that was a helpful link. I wonder if i just did it as a bridge using open and close - will need to give it further thought

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example using a uniform distribution.

```
runif(NUMSAMP, min=LOW, max=HIGH)
```

Look at ?distribution for ideas on others.